# Pointer points to an address I didn't expect

Tags: c++, list, pointers, struct, memory-address

I don't understand why `t->next` points to a different address than `t`. If the `t->next` pointer is equal to the address of `n` and the `t` pointer is equal to address of `t->next` why does `t->next` seem to point to a different adress? I'm stuck here.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

 int main() {
    Node* n;
    Node* t;
    Node* h;

    n = new Node;
    t = new Node;

    n->data = 2;
    t->next = n;
    t = t->next;

    cout << n << "\n" << n->data << "\n" << t << "\n" << t->next << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
0x7a11c8
2
0x7a11c8
0x65685372
```

Comment: You didn't initialize `n->next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following after `t = new Node` each of the following lines make the following changes.

**Memory allocated for n & t.**

```
n->+-----------+  t->+-----------+
   |data = ?   |     |data = ?   |
   |next = ?   |     |next = ?   |
   +-----------+     +-----------+
```

**Value assigned to `data` element of memory referenced by n.**

```
n-data = 2;
```

```
n->+-----------+  t->+-----------+
   |data = 2   |     |data = ?   |
   |next = ?   |     |next = ?   |
   +-----------+     +-----------+
```

**Value assigned to `next` element of memory referenced by t.**
And this happens be the location of n.

```
t->next = n;
```

```
n->+-----------+  t->+-----------+
   |data = 2   |     |data = ?   |
+->|next = ?   |     |next = @n  |--+
|  +-----------+     +-----------+  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

**Value of t redirected to reference same memory as `t.next` (which is currently `n`).**
You should observe that at no point did you set the `next` element of n.

```
t = t->next;
```

```
                     vv orphan vv
n->+-----------+     +-----------+
t->|data = 2   |     |data = ?   |
+->|next = ?   |     |next = @n  |--+
|  +-----------+     +-----------+  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

***WARNING*** You've also lost your only reference the location of memory allocated in `t = new Node;`. So you have a memory leak.

Comment: Perhaps the important thing to realise is that ***old*** `t->next == n` but by changing `t`, you effectively have change `t->data` and `t-next` as well.

Comment: I selected your answer for explaining what was wrong visually and step by step. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, you indeed have `t->next == n` so they should point to the same address. However, further you do `t = t->next`, so `t` points now to a different node (the same node pointed as by `n`, to be specific) and its `next` is uninitialized, hence a "random" value is at the end of your output. Should you print out just `t` you should see the same value as the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be.
You do `t = t->next` - after that, `n == t`. But then, you request `t->next` which was not set

Sample code:

```
t->next = n; // t->next == n
t = t->next; // t == t->next == n
// calling t->next
std::cout << t; // t == n
std::cout << t->next; // the same as n->next or t->next->next for previous state of t
```

So what you see is: n points to the same place as t does. t->next - somewhere else, obviously.

By the way, lists are easy after you draw the whole picture. It all becomes clear

Answer (score 0):

this is the basic of linked list, a class contains a pointer to another object of the same class so pointer n has data and the address for the next object, the next object also the same thing behaves and so on...

```
Node* n;
Node* t;

n = new Node;
n->data = 2;
n->next = NULL;

t = new Node;
t->data = 5;
t->next = n; // link the nodes


//t = t->next; // why this it like moving in linked list through nodes
```

now t has data 5 and its next pointer points to n which has data 2

the next pointer of n points to NULL;